# Access Database - Error of 'Single'

Tags: database

I get the error 'Single' from the line `SingleRoom = dr("Single").ToString` . I've not been programming for long. I want to be able to search the database for the most recent date (Last Modified) and then use the data from the other fields in the same row to display as labels.

```
Dim PriceFound As String = False
    MyConn = New OleDbConnection 
    MyConn.ConnectionString = connString 
    MyConn.Open() 


    str1 = ("SELECT `Last Modified` FROM [Prices] ORDER BY `Last Modified` DESC") 


    Dim cmd1 As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand(str1, MyConn)

    dr = cmd1.ExecuteReader 

    While dr.Read() 

        PriceFound = True 
        DateDisplay = dr("Last Modified").ToString
        SingleRoom = dr("Single").ToString 
        DoubleRoom = dr("Double").ToString 
        FamilyRoom = dr("Family").ToString 
        AdultPrice = dr("Adult").ToString 
        ChildPrice = dr("Child").ToString

        If PriceFound = True Then
            LblPriceAdult.Text = AdultPrice
            LblPriceChild.Text = ChildPrice
            LblPriceDoubleRoom.Text = DoubleRoom
            LblPriceFamilyRoom.Text = FamilyRoom
            LblPriceSingleRoom.Text = SingleRoom
        End If
    End While
    MyConn.Close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query should likely be:

```
"SELECT * FROM [Prices] ORDER BY `Last Modified` DESC"
```

...so that it will retrieve the other columns/fields in the SELECT clause. The current query only retrieves the `Last Modified` column.

=====

Also, if you'd like to only choose specific columns, you could do this in the query:

Note that the column order is **NOT** important -- I simply matched your list in this example.

```
"SELECT `Last Modified`, Single, Double, Family, Adult, Child FROM [Prices] ORDER BY `Last Modified` DESC"
```